how to limit the line chart dimension for only past 12 months and each month should show summation of past 12 months to that particular month
I have to create a qliksense line chart with dimension which shows only past 12 months from current date as dimension and measure should be rolling 12 month summation of past 12 months to that particular month even though that months are not shown in dimension value.
For example in x axis, we will be having data from Aug-23 to Jul-24. And in y axis the count of total number of notifications should be present in a manner that Aug-23 value should be summation from Sept-22 to Aug-23 data even though Sept-22 is not shown in x axis.
The below given are the things what I had tried:
Dimension : =If(Report_MonthYear >= monthstart(addmonths(today(),-12)) and Report_MonthYear <= monthstart(addmonths(today(),-1)),Report_MonthYear)

Measure : 
RangeSum(Above(Count(distinct {<
Report_MonthYear -= { "$(='>=' & Date(AddMonths(TruncateMonth(Today()),-12),'MMM-YYYY'))<=' & Date(TruncateMonth(Today()),'MMM-YYYY')"} >} Notification),0,12))


You can try this function:
Sum({<Report_MonthYear = {"$(='<=' & Today() & '>' & AddMonths(Today(),-12))"}>} 
    Aggr(
        RangeSum(Above(Aggr(Sum(Notifications), Report_MonthYear), 0, 12)), Report_MonthYear
        )
    )

The trick is that the set expression of the outer aggregation sum() is not being considered in the inner aggregation RangeSum(), so we can calculate over the months older than a year back, but only show the results of the months within the last year.
This piece of documentation is quite helpful.
